# Which do I have to use between "by" and "as" in front of Mathematical equations in scientific papers?

Tags: prepositions

When I write some scientific papers, which do I have to use between "by" and "as" in the following sentences?

With "define":

```
The maximum amount of energy that the i-th
IoT device can harvest is defined as/by
               Equation.               (1)
```

With "obtain":

```
The maximum amount of energy that the i-th
IoT device can harvest is obtained as/by
               Equation.               (2)
```

With "achieve":

```
The maximum amount of energy that the i-th
IoT device can harvest is achieved as/by
               Equation.               (3)
```

With "derive"

```
The maximum amount of energy that the i-th
IoT device can harvest is derived as/by
               Equation.               (4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Defined by*, or *shown by*, or *calculated by*, or *can be obtained from*.

Usually, *derived* refers to the equation, as in
*The equation is derived from...*

Comment: According to your word, is the following wrong? The capacity, C, with respect to x and y is obtained by C(x,y) = f(x)+g(y)+h(x,y).

Comment: However, in my opinion, the following sentence is kind of different from what I want to say: The capacity, C, with respect to x and y is obtained from C(x,y) = f(x)+g(y)+h(x,y).

Comment: @Danny_Kim I don't think the verb *obtain* fits there. If you are defining $C(x,y)$, I would use the word define. If you are merely stating a formula for $C(x,y)$, then I would say "is" or "is given by" rather than "is obtained by."